reading values from registers/sensors with CIP protocol in wireshark
A little background, I have 120 sensors that return values ​​(temperature, pressure, altitude, etc.) Using the CIP protocol, I am trying through wireshark to monitor the reactions of the sensors and see the values ​​it return.
For example, to understand which sensor returns a temperature and what value it returns (like temp = 30 - i know it wont be in decimal)
I am sharing here several images from the wireshark.
I would appreciate some guidance on how I can read the data that the sensors return to me.
the total info of the response
more specific data on the registers that i think that from here i should get the values
I'm used to working with the MODBUS protocol and there the reading from the registers is much clearer, An example of a response from the registers in the MODBUS protocol
